# Problems with ref focus using componentDidUpdate + opacity and visibility animation in css

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to `focus()` an input inside a modal right after it opens using the modal's `componentDidUpdate()`.

This is the CSS I'm using for the modal root element:

```
.auth-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 400ms, opacity 400ms;

  &.auth-modal_is-opened {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

As you can see, it has `visibility: hidden;` and `opacity: 0;` at first.

Then I have this in the modal component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.emailInput.focus();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.emailInput.focus();
}
```

The `componentDidMount()` hook works as intended, the input gets focused, but the `componentDidUpdate()` hook does not work (as though it gets called, only the `focus()` doesn't work as intended).

I've managed to find the reason and it happens to be the CSS animation. If I remove the `visibility` animation it works (but the animation breaks, of course). I've also managed to make it work using a `setTimeout()` inside the hook as bellow:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.emailInput.focus();
  }, 100);
}
```

This also works, but feels super hackish.

Is there any better way to achieve this? (I'm currently setting a timeout as a hack solution)

Comment: It would be much better if you can provide whatever you have done so far.

Comment: @HardikModha I think it's more clear now.

Comment: can you give us the full component? it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish with the focus on update. there may be a better lifecycle method for this if we can see it all